# How do I access a hash that is not appended to the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor

Is there a way to get the hash value from an anchor tag like `<a href="#menu1">Link</a>` that is not getting appended to the URL when it's clicked ([example page](http://www.dogsinc.net/)) ? I would usually use `location.hash`, which unfortunately does not work in this case.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    if(click_on_anchor_link) {
         var hash= document.location.hash;
         return hash;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by retrieve the hash value? Are you wanting to get `menu1`?

Comment: You could select the anchor and getAttibute('href'). But if clicking this link doesn't make the hash appear in the URL at the top of the browser, you have another bug somewhere.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE], all else being equal, that fragment identifier **will** be appended to the URL when the link is clicked. You also need to explain **when** you want to get the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can by using [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) property:

```js
var a = document.createElement('a'); // or getElementById or whatever
a.href = '#menu1';
console.log(a.hash); //#menu1

a.href = 'http://example.com/myPage#menu2';
console.log(a.hash); //#menu2
```